# Responsive triangle with border to container's height and width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, css-shapes

**The Problem**

I need to create a container box that contains a triangle outline that's responsive to the size of the container, here's an image example as it's a lot simpler:

[image: triangle risizing to the size of the container]

**Requirements**

- The triangle should resize to the height and width of it's container, it does not need to maintain it's aspect ratio meaning that the base and points of the triangle should touch the sides of the container like in the attached image.
- The triangle should have a clear and not blurred 1px border
- The triangle should have a background `#fff`
- The box should have a 2px border
- The box should have a background `#fff`

**Issues**

I've tried something basic with borders around the child div but positioning it dynamically with relative width and height is proving as issue.

As is only getting the outline of a triangle and not a fully coloured triangle. This means creating the triangle using border becomes more complex unless someone can work out how to position one on top of another to give the white background with 1px border effect as in the image?

**An Example**

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yafpmmxa/)**

```
.pane{
    border:1px solid #000;
    height:500px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:150px;
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
}

.triangle{
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 250px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 250px solid transparent;
    border-left: 250px solid #ff0000;
}


<div class="pane">
    <div class="triangle">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Example 2**

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/58dVS/194/)**

This example creates responsive triangles but they'd need to be flipped and have the wider sections absolutely positioned `left:0; right:0; top:0;`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67236/discussion-on-question-by-silver89-responsive-triangle-with-border-to-container).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the units you are using for your container, and if it's size depends on viewport, you can achieve this behaviour with [`vw/vh` units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths) :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/kmenstqs/)**

```css
div{width:0;outline:1px solid red;}
.r{
    border-top:15vh solid transparent;
    border-bottom:15vh solid transparent;
    border-left:50vw solid teal;
}
.t{
    border-left:15vw solid transparent;
    border-right:15vw solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50vh solid gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="r"></div>
<div class="t"></div>
```

---

If you only want the outline of the triangle and if you have a plain background, you can use this approach :

The point is to position an other triangle with the same color as the background over the first one :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/kmenstqs/1/)**

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
.r {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 30vh;
  border-left: 2px solid teal;
}
.t {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 30vw;
  border-bottom: 2px solid gold;
}
.r:after,
.r:before,
.t:after,
.t:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.r:before,
.r:after {
  border-top: 15vh solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15vh solid transparent;
  border-left: 50vw solid teal;
}
.r:after {
  border-left-color: #fff;
  left: -1vw;
}
.t:before,
.t:after {
  border-left: 15vw solid transparent;
  border-right: 15vw solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50vh solid gold;
}
.t:after {
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
  bottom: -1vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="r"></div>
<div class="t"></div>
```

Comment: `vh` and `vw` units are equal to the size of the **window**, not a specific container.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly you are right, added and `if` statement in the answer.

Comment: Also how about the issue of only getting the triangle outline / border as in the image?

Comment: @Silver89 do you have a plain background?

Comment: The container would have a `border:1px solid #000;` as would the triangle, they then both have `background:#fff;`

Comment: @Silver89 that requirement is different to what you've specified in the question. The question asks for responsive triangles, *not* for triangles with backgrounds.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly "As is only getting the outline of a triangle and not a fully coloured triangle. "

Comment: @Silver89 you can use this approach to make only the outline of the triangles : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/kmenstqs/1/

Comment: @web-tiki: I ended up with 'blurry' lines, but it did *work*. But i'd say your solution would be more robust than mine, anyway :P So hence the +1

Comment: @jbutler483 thanks, is this less blurry http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/kmenstqs/2/ ?

Comment: sorry sorry, I'm completely out of sync today. I was saying *my answer* was blurry, and yours was a **better** solution. :!

Comment: @jbutler483 I just reread your comment and I think I was the one to be out of sync ^^ anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[See here](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/R3K7y/312/)

- this uses a great technique, using gradients to create the shape.
- you might want to fiddle with it and see:

```css
body, html {height: 100%}
#triangleWrapper {
    width: 100px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid black;

}

.segmentTriangle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, black 50%, transparent 50%)
}
```

```html
    <div style="float: left;" id="triangleWrapper">
        <div style="height: 100%;" class="segmentTriangle"></div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

**[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/R3K7y/313/)**

---

## Only outline

---

By using the power of gradients, you can create pure outlines, like this one:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
#triangleWrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.segmentTriangle {
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to left top, transparent 49%, black 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(to left bottom, transparent 49%, black 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="triangleWrapper">
  <div class="segmentTriangle"></div>
</div>
```

---

## Update

---

[Right Triangle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/R3K7y/314/)

[Up Triangle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/R3K7y/316/)

[Down Triangle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/R3K7y/317/)

[Left Triangle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/R3K7y/318/)

---

**NOTE**
to ensure the 'border' doesn't get cut off, you can set `overflow:hidden;` on the parent container

Comment: It's almost there, just need an isosceles as opposed to right triangle?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: see 'new updated answer'

Comment: even if the lines are blurry, this solution does work as the size of the triangle depends on the size of the container whatever units are used : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/v1cczusd/

Comment: [this is too much fun! :P](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/v1cczusd/1/)

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://codeitdown.com/css-triangles-responsive/) seems to has a nice solution for responsive triangles with pure CSS

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/a20oo6eu/1/)**

```css
.triangle-up {
  width: 25%;
  height: 0;
  padding-left: 25%;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid brown;
  margin: 20px;
}
.triangle-up div {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: -500px;
  border-left: 500px solid transparent;
  border-right: 500px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 500px solid #4679BD;
}
.triangle-right {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 25%;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
  padding-left: 25%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 20px;
}
.triangle-right div {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-top: -500px;
  margin-left: -500px;
  border-top: 500px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 500px solid transparent;
  border-left: 500px solid tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-up">
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="triangle-right">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This would be the one if it were just the outlines of the triangles!

Comment: I need the triangles to have a white background and 1px border, solid border triangles don't allow that?

Comment: The triangles just need to be the size of the container without distortion

Comment: @web-tiki - the OP says: "Basically the triangle should resize without distorting.." so I figured that the triangles do need to keep their aspect ratios

Comment: When I say distortion I mean the box shouldn't be a gif file triangle background that just gets stretched to the size of the container.

Comment: This doesn't seem very responsive to me. If I change the width of your `.triangle-up` element from 25% to 10% the triangle gets cut off.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: It seems OP's requirements have changed from what we thought. It's almost "auto scale a triangle, but it must be the outline of a triangle, and the triangle should fill the container, but not distort". Sounds like conflicting requirements, (to me anyway).

Comment: @web-tiki: i've tried my best in order to *guess* what they were looking for, but it's probably not 'exactly' what they're looking for

Answer (score 0):

**If you can use SVG that this solution can work for you.**

You can use SVG for creating arrow that change according to its parent. You can see working arrow (different arrow what you are using) at http://css-tricks.com/. When you scroll down for 2nd article link, you can see the arrow. If you will change the arrow parent anchor tag width, and height and set its block property to block. You will see that arrow is changing according to its parent. You can use Inspect bar in any browser to view result.